# Encrypted email VS SSL data transfer: which is better?

Tags: http, email, ssl, encryption, server

I have a client who want me to set up a reliable and very secure way of transferring health data from his clients to a server for analysis.

The problem that I am having is that he is very intent on using encrypted email as a way of transferring the data.

Here are some of my objections to this idea (I could be wrong):

- Email is unreliable
- Email is slow
- Email is very limited by size of data

I would prefer using a UI that lets his clients upload their data and sends it securely through SSL to the server for analysis.

I would be using Angular to create the UI. The data would probably use a POST request to be sent to the server (unless there is a better way that I haven't heard of).

Am I wrong to shiver at the idea of using email?

Which one would be best?

Is there another better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Email is unreliable

For starters, email isn't encrypted unless you use a plugin of some sort.

If this is a batch operation, use an sftp server and sftp client software. It's designed specifically to transfer files over an encrypted link.

Unless you have a huge Professional Errors & Omission policy, I wouldn't write a single line of code for this, and would recommend using known-secure software that already exists.

You don't want to be inventing your own encryption for something that  could get you sued into the dirt if compromised.